Incorrect output(but very close) when appending values from one worksheet to another using openpyxl
The code snip below is very close to creating the correct output, but it's missing some of the required rows and adding a few rows that it shouldn't, and I can't figure out why.
LU = "Gilford"

for i, row in enumerate(sourcews2.iter_rows(min_row=5, min_col= 1, max_col=33)):
        if sourcews2.cell(row=i+1, column=1).value == LU:
            destinationws.append([cell.value for cell in row])

The rows in the image below, where the first cell = Gilford, are the rows I'm trying to extract and append to a different excel sheet.

The output results in the other excel sheet look like the image below. It's missing 4 of the rows from the top of the Gilford stack in the source worksheet, and also adding the 4 rows that follow the Gilford stack, which start with "Gray". Referring to the code snip above, I don't know how or why it would pull the rows starting with "Gray".


sourcews2.cell(row=i+1, column=1) is "off" by 4 rows.

That's all that it was. I didn't account for rows at the top that had the table info and column names. Thank you! But I'm still confused why it would grab the 'Gray' rows because I have the if statement?

For the same reason, because sourcews2.cell(row=i+1, column=1) and [cell.value for cell in row] are not the same row.

It's not a very efficient way of doing what you're doing but, you do know that enumerate can start at whatever number you choose, as in for i, row in enumerate(sourcews2.iter_rows(min_row=5, min_col= 1, max_col=33),5): will start i counting from 5 so it'd be in sync with row. But then you immediately see why your implementation is inefficient.

Aaah, okay, that makes total sense now. I don't know if I would have ever figured that out. Thanks for the explanations.

row[0].row is the row number you are currently searching, i is redundant.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Is there a method or function in openpyxl that can be used for specifying what cell to append the data to in the destination worksheet? I can't find anything like that.
Instead, it's looking like I'll have to figure it out using destinationws.cell(row= , column= ).value = cell.value

Moken has already provided the solution but I'll just add that if you're using ws.iter_rows() you'll almost never need to use ws.cell() in the same code. In your case cell.offset() would make more sense, but that would be redundant because you have all the cells in the row.

You don't need to worry about the append that is automatic.
Your code will work you just don't need the extra count i.
Openpyxl append will always add data to the next unused row. That is the next row after the last row that contains a cell with a value other than None.
The data must be provided as a list or dictionary. 

For a list the data is add to the row as, first element goes in the first column ('A') the second into the second column ('B') and so on for all elements.
For a dictonary the value is entered into the column specified by the key. So for destinationws.append({'A': 'Value1', 'C': 'Value2'}), 'Value1' is entered into column A and 'Value2' is entered into column C.

AND always into the next unused row.

All you need is the following;
In each iter_rows iteration row[0] is the first cell in the row, i.e. column A so row[0].value is the value in the cell where you are searching for 'Gilford'.
Once found then create your list as you do and since the row in your list creation is the same row as you are currently searching for 'Gilford', the data selected will be for the correct row.
Then append that data. The list is added to the next unused row.
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook


sourcewb = load_workbook('data.xlsx')
sourcews2 = sourcewb['Sheet1']

destinationwb = Workbook()
destinationws = destinationwb.active

LU = "Gilford"

for row in sourcews2.iter_rows(min_row=5, min_col=1, max_col=33):
    if row[0].value == LU:
        destinationws.append([cell.value for cell in row])

destinationwb.save('new.xlsx')


As the cell coordinates are irrelevant, you can use values_only=True here and then just pass the row to append. And it's probably possible to use read_only=True on the workbook. Combining this with write-only is a good pattern when possible.
